# How to get azure virtual machine CPU utilization and memory uses?

Tags: c#, azure

I am working in a program where I need to calculate virtual machine CPU utilization and memory uses.

For that I have used azure insight matrix, but I am not getting CPU utilization kind of thing. Is there any API exists where I can find CPU kind of information?

Answer (score 0):

To get the CPU Utilization and Memory Usage you should go to your VM on the portal and enable Diagnostics then you'll be able to retrieve those data.

[image]

After that, you need to access WADPerformanceCountersTable in the storage account that is setup to store diagnostic data.

Here is the help page to help with connecting Java to table storage: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/how-to-guides/table-service/